# Pythonic way to get headers when writing a List[Dict] to CSV when the keys are not constant

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have a list of dictionaries which I need to write to a csv file. Before, the keys of the dicts were ordinal so I could get the keys of the largest dict as my columns and be sure that I have all the column names used in other dicts:

```
from csv import DictWriter

data = [{"1":"a", "2":"b", "3":"c", "4":"d", "5":"e"}, {"1":"a", "2":"b", "3":"c", "4":"d", "5":"e"}, {"1":"a", "2":"b", "3":"c", "4":"d"}, {"1":"a"}]

with open(location, "w", newline="") as file:
    csv_dict_writer = DictWriter(file, max(data, key=len).keys())
    csv_dict_writer.writeheader()
    csv_dict_writer.writerows(data)
```

Now, the keys are not ordinal anymore. Accordingly, at times it happens that getting the keys of the largest dict will not cover all the keys used in other dictionaries. This gives me an error. What I am doing now to solve this problem is this:

```
from csv import DictWriter

data = [{"1":"a", "2":"b", "3":"c", "4":"d", "5":"e"}, {"1":"a", "2":"b", "3":"c", "4":"d", "6":"f"}, {"7":"g", "2":"b", "3":"c", "4":"d"}, {"8":"h"}]

with open(location, "w", newline="") as file:
    csv_dict_writer = DictWriter(file, {key for elem in data for key in elem.keys()})
    csv_dict_writer.writeheader()
    csv_dict_writer.writerows(data)
```

This solution does lose the order of the keys which is not a big thing but still a loss. I checked other people's solutions on the web and I think mine is actually better than most. However, my main problem is that it feels a little hack-ish compared to the previous. Does anyone know of a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create sorted list of all keys and then use `dict.get` when writing rows:

```
from csv import DictWriter


data = [{"1":"a", "2":"b", "3":"c", "4":"d", "5":"e"}, {"1":"a", "2":"b", "3":"c", "4":"d", "6":"f"}, {"7":"g", "2":"b", "3":"c", "4":"d"}, {"8":"h"}]
all_keys = sorted({k for d in data for k in d})

with open('data.csv', "w", newline="") as file:
    csv_dict_writer = DictWriter(file, all_keys)
    csv_dict_writer.writeheader()
    
    for d in data:
        row = {k: d.get(k) for k in all_keys}
        csv_dict_writer.writerow(row)
```

Creates this csv (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: What difference does sorted make here? I am getting the same thing with and without it.

Comment: @mnsr Depends on Python version, in versions of python prior to 3.7 (3.6?) dictionaries were unsorted. So it's safe bet to sort them (but if you're sure, you can skip this step).

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using pandas this is trivial

```
data = [{"1":"a", "2":"b", "3":"c", "4":"d", "5":"e"}, 
        {"1":"a", "2":"b", "3":"c", "4":"d", "6":"f"}, 
        {"7":"g", "2":"b", "3":"c", "4":"d"}, 
        {"8":"h"}]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('filename.csv',index=None)
df

     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
0    a    b    c    d    e  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    a    b    c    d  NaN    f  NaN  NaN
2  NaN    b    c    d  NaN  NaN    g  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    h
```

Comment: That actually is a good way of doing it. The only problem is that I can't add pandas to the project. But I like that. I may use it in other projects.